# PrimeFaces Poll

Tags: java, ajax, mobile, primefaces

I try to make a site where I place a clock. Not a default primefaces clock because I need the actual time not just to show it. I use Netbeans8.0, Java8.0, Primefaces5.0, and I'm building a Mobile site.

So I tried the p:poll but it not works for me.

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "navigationTo")
public class NavigationTo implements Serializable{

    private int number;

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void increment() {
        number++;
    }
}

<h:body>
        <pm:page id="index">
            <pm:header title="xyz"></pm:header>
            <pm:content>
                <h:form>
                    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true"/>
                    <h:outputText id="txt_count" value="#{navigationTo.number}" />
                    <p:poll interval="3" listener="#{navigationTo.increment}" update="txt_count" />
                    <p:graphicImage value="xyz.png" style="width: 30%;
```

I use this default primefaces example but only shows the 0 and it's not incrementing...

Anyone any idea?

!!!EDIT: Primefaces Mobile (here: pm) not support polling. So it only work with the basic primefaces.

Comment: Have you tried the plain example from the PrimeFaces showcase? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/poll.xhtml Also you can take a look in the JavaScript console in your browser and check for any errors. Last I would set a break point or println in your listener method to see whether it gets fired correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, I look your situation, I did a example about it, It work for me!

I have created a Bean similar to your bean.

```
    @ViewScoped
    @ManagedBean(name="clockBean")
   public class clockBean implements Serializable{

        private  int number;

        public void increment(){
           number++;
        }

        public int getNumber() {
          return number;
        }

        public void setNumber(int number) {
          this.number = number;
        }
}
```

Besides I created a simple web page

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">
  <ui:composition template="/layout/template.xhtml">
  <ui:define name="body">
   <h:form id="form">
            <p:poll interval="1"
                listener="#{clockBean.increment}" update=":form" />
            <p:outputLabel value="#{clockBean.number}" />
    </h:form>
  </ui:define>
  </ui:composition> 

 </html>
```

It has worked for me, I hope it can help you!.

I think that your problem is that you need use id for the different components in your web page for exaMple the component form, it should has a id.

Comment: Sorry I solved this problem. The problem is that Primefaces Mobile not support polling. By the way your answer is working as it has to.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="primefaces.js" />
```

inside *h:body* solved for me. I'm using PrimeFaces 5.1.20

Answer (score 0):

For me, adding this line to `<h:body>` helped:

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces/poll" name="poll.js" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you debugged the actual navigationTo.increment method, and checked that the poll actually goes inside?

It seems that you are missing attributes inside the poll, if you want to trigger the back end method, and start the actual poll as soon as you load the page, add this:

```
process="@this" autoStart="true"
```